# Congratulations for reaching 100k reputation points, Thomas Markov!

Tags: discussion, reputation, just-for-fun, users

While browsing the site, I noticed that [Thomas Markov](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/62294/thomas-markov) has reached 100,000 reputation points on RPG.SE:

[image: 100.000 reputation points]

With 79 questions and 1,182 answers, he can be very frequently seen around the site helping out where he can. I hope we continue to have you around, continuing to share your knowledge with the community.

Answer (score 12):

#### Thanks RPG.SE

I want to apologize for being so slow to respond to this, I do appreciate the shout out.

More importantly, I want to thank this community. RPG.SE has ignited a passion in me for tabletop gaming that will last a lifetime. I've made new friends, learned a lot, and grown as a person thanks to many of you. I hope to have the privilege of enjoying many more years as a part of this community.

Comment: Happy to have you here.